# How to allow/restrict a certificate to issue another certificate?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

How to make a leaf certificate that can't sign other certificates? Does ica have anything that defines that it can issue other certificates?
Would like if one can provide examples using openssl.

Comment: *"How to make a leaf certificate that can't sign other certificates?"* - that's the very point of a leaf certificate that it cannot sign others. Otherwise it would not be a leaf certificate. But the certificate attribute you are looking for is Basic Constraints CA:false.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Steffen in the comments, a CA can issue certificates when it has the v3 extension `basicConstraints=CA:true`. A root CA works even without it as the issuer is same as subject, which implicitly implies its a CA.

From the docs:

> **Basic Constraints.**
> This is a multi valued extension which indicates whether a certificate
> is a CA certificate. The first (mandatory) name is CA followed by TRUE
> or FALSE. If CA is TRUE then an optional pathlen name followed by an
> non-negative value can be included.

To ensure only a certain number of certs are issued down the chain, another extension is used: `pathlen:1`.

From the docs:

> The pathlen parameter indicates the maximum number of CAs that can
> appear below this one in a chain. So if you have a CA with a pathlen
> of zero it can only be used to sign end user certificates and not
> further CAs.

There are other useful extensions that can be found in openssl documentation [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man5/x509v3_config.html).